# Nested FormView controls

Tags: asp.net, nested, formview

I have an asp.net form that looks something like this...

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelForm" runat="server" >
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" >
        <asp:EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" >
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="myControl" runat="server" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
        </asp:EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to set the text of a `TextBox` called "myControl" to "myText".

The code below results in `t = null` which throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

```
FormView fv2 = (FormView)FormView1.FindControl("FormView2");
fv2.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
TextBox t = (TextBox)fv2.FindControl("myControl");
t.Text = "myText";
```

How to update this `TextBox` from the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a DataBind()...

```
FormView fv2 = (FormView)FormView1.FindControl("FormView2");
fv2.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
fv2.DataBind();
TextBox t = (TextBox)(fv2.FindControl("myControl"));
t.Text = "myText";
```

Doh!